# How to transform text in css for the windows vista and windows 7 IE 8 Browsers

Tags: css, transform

How to transform the text in windows vista and windows 7 IE browsers. I tried

```
.banner h1{
   color:#fff;
   -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
   -moz-transform:rotate(270deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0, M12=1, M21=-1, M22=0,sizingMethod='auto expand') !important;    
   /*-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0, M12=1, M21=-1, M22=0,sizingMethod='auto expand')";*/
   -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) !important;
   /*-sand-transform: rotate(270deg) !important; */
   display:block;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:100px;
   background:url(images/header_text_bg.png) no-repeat left top;
   border:none;
   line-height:44px;
   font-size:19px;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width: 245px;
   border:none;
   text-indent: 13px;
   z-index: 9999;
   left: -100px;
   *left:0;
   *bottom:3px;
}
```

It works fine in all browsers including windows XP IE 8 browsers. When the same thing is tested in the Vista and Windows 7 the text is not transformed. I tried -ms-filter. That didnt sorted out. Kindly help me to sort out this. Working with this from last evening. Thanks in advance

Comment: Windows Vista and Windows 7? It has only to do with Browser, nothing with the OS, and as far aas the answer goes, you need CSS3 Pie

Comment: I agree, But when my tester test the website in WindowsXP's IE browser text transforms works, when the same thing is tested in Vista and win7 IE browser transform and filter is not working.

Comment: text transform and transforms are 2 different things

Comment: Mis spelled. transforms not working in vista and windows7 IE browser.Please guide me

Comment: all other browser works fine, only in the vista and windows IE 8 browsers transform, filter, -sand-transform,-ms-filter nothing working.